# Readable streams failing before it can be used

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, coffeescript, stream

Im having the following problem. I have a readable stream which i want to write to a s3 bucket.

Before i write the file to the s3 bucket i do a HEAD request to check that the file isn't already there. Once i get a response from the HEAD request i begin upload using the stream mentioned above.

The thing is that the stream ends by the time the i get a reply from the head request, so the upload doesn't work as intended.

I've tried running the PUT straight away and it works as intended :).

Any idea's on how to debug why the stream is ending early? 
Is it common for streams to end when you leave them waiting too long?

Example Code (Doesn't work):

```
req.on "response", (response) =>
  # Analyse the head response and discard un-necessary information
  head_status = parseInt response.statusCode
  response.resume()

  #if head_status is 404 or Math.floor(head_status / 100) is 3 # Handle redirects
  console.log("HERE")
  logger.debug "S3 Multipart Upload", id

  upload = new MultiPartUpload {
    client: @s3
    objectName: id
    stream: stream
    headers: {'content-type': content_type}
    noDisk: true
  }, (err, body) ->
    console.log("Got to here!!!")
    if err?
      logger.debug "Unable to PUT stream to S3 for", id, err
      callback new Error(err)
      return
    else
      callback null, {success: true, id: id}
```

Example Code (Does Work)

```
upload = new MultiPartUpload {
        client: @s3
        objectName: id
        stream: stream
        headers: {'content-type': content_type}
        noDisk: true
      }, (err, body) ->
        console.log("Got to here!!!")
        if err?
          logger.debug "Unable to PUT stream to S3 for", id, err
          callback new Error(err)
          return
        else
          callback null, {success: true, id: id}
```

Comment: How are you getting the `stream` ?

Comment: I fetch an image from s3, run it through a node js resizing library called graphics magick. So the stream comes from graphics magick ( A popular node js image manipulation library)